# how can i display message below a table created using while loop in php

Tags: php, sql, while-loop

this is the display page.i want to dislay message after while loop gets over below the table .the code below displays the message beside the table.
I want to echo a message such as "data fetched sucessfully" below the table

```
<?php
session_start();
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Could not Connect");
$db=mysql_select_db("practice",$con);
if($_SESSION['user']=="")
{
    header("location:login.php");

}
if(isset($_GET['status']))
{
    $status=$_GET['status'];
    if($status==sucess)
    {
        echo "<h2>Details Updated Succesfully....!!</h2>";
    }
}
echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION['user'];
echo "<br>";
$page=$_GET['page'];
if($page=="" || $page=="1")
{
$page1=0;
}
else
{

  $page1=($page*4)-4;
  }
$query="SELECT * FROM `details` LIMIT $page1,4";
$result=mysql_query($query,$con);
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($numrows>0)
{?>
<table  align="left"  border="1" >
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>NAME</th>
  <th>USERNAME</th>
  <th>PASSWORD</th>
  <th>Hobbies</th>
  <th>E-MAIL</th>
  <th>GENDER</th>
  <th>CONTACT</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
 <?php
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {?>
 <tr>
  <td><?php  echo $row['name'];?></td>
  <td><?php  echo $row['username'];?></td>
  <td><?php  echo $row['password'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['hobbies'];?></td>
  <td><?php  echo $row['email'];?></td>
  <td><?php  echo $row['gender'];?></td>
  <td><?php  echo $row['contact'];?></td>
  <td><a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">Update</a></td>
  <td><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">Delete</a></td>
 </tr>
<?php

}
echo "data fetched sucessfully";


  ?> 
</tbody>
</table>
</br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
  <?php
$query1="SELECT * FROM `details`";
$result=mysql_query($query1,$con);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
$a=ceil($count/4);

for($b=1;$b<=$a;$b++)
{
?><a href="welcome.php?page=<?php echo $b; ?>" style="text-decoration:none"><?php echo $b."";?> </a>



<?php

}

}
else
{
echo "NO Record";

}
mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: Just after `</tbody>`  put your message.what's the problem?

Comment: its showing the message beside the table..not bellow it

Comment: you need to add some css for it to come to down.

Comment: can u help me out with it

Comment: Can you put your message in your question after `<tbody>`. i want to see it?

Comment: check it now...edited the question

Comment: it shows the message "data fetched syucessfully" beside the table

Comment: Well why not echo with html code like echo <br>message or something like that, that will go into next line, of course that echo will go afther all table html

Comment: echo also gives the content beside the table

Comment: You'll need to add this after your `</table>` in order to adhere to html standards, but `echo "<br />data fetched sucessfully";` should get you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
echo "data fetched sucessfully";
?> 
</tbody>
</table>
```

means the message is inside your table. It just needs to come after the closing table tag instead.

```
?> 
</tbody>
</table>
<?php echo "data fetched sucessfully"; ?>
```

I think the `align="left"` in your `<table>` tag is what is causing the message to display beside it. It would be a good idea to remove it anyway, because this attribute [has been deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-TABLE) and should not be used. If you need to control the position of the table, you can use CSS instead.

Comment: its giving the same problem after the closing </table> tag also

Comment: @ankitasimlai Does your page have a style sheet? There could be some CSS causing this.

Comment: no it has got no stylesheet.i have given the entire  page in coding

Comment: @ankitasimlai The problem was not what I originally thought it was. I edited the answer after I noticed something else.